# Python only find string with specific length numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to create a script that search for strings of numbers with only specific length numbers from an output.txt.

Example output.txt:

```
12345678
77777
12123887
```

When I use:

```
import re 
f = open('output.txt', 'r')
strings = re.findall(r'(\d{5,5})', f.read())
print strings
```

I would like to get only output: `77777` instead of:

```
12345
77777
12123
```

Comment: Does it have to be regex?

Comment: Regex is actually suitable. AFAIK you cannot easily check classes of characters in simple `if char in line` statements.

Answer (score 3):

Use `^(\d{5})$` and `re.MULTILINE`

```
>>> import re
>>> data = '''12345678
77777
12123887'''
>>> p = re.compile(r'^(\d{5})$', re.MULTILINE)
>>> re.findall(p, data)
['77777']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex solution. This can be done by just getting the length of each name and getting the one of interest by also validating `isdigit`:

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
    file_names = [name.strip() for name in f.readlines() if name.strip().isdigit() and len(name.strip()) == 5]

print(file_names)
```

Comment: thanks! This is what I was looking for! It now only gives the digits and not different chars that has 5 chars.

Comment: @Jessekraal That was what you were looking for, right? Only files with digits in them? Or were you looking for any string that has to be length of 5?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify boundaries what you expect: you expect 5 digit not surrounded by other digits:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
   strings=re.findall(r'\b(\d{5})\b', f.read())
   print strings
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line = f.read()
line.rstrip()
if len(line) == 5 and not re.match('[^\d]', line):
    print(line)
```

`len` is pretty quick and you keep your regex as simple as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

this should work fine for you ..

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
file_str = f.read()

for line in str.split(file_str):
    if len(line) == 5: # you can manipulate the number 5 as you like .
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex-based solution, you should use [`\b`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for that :

```
strings = re.findall(r'\b\d{5}\b', f.read()) # Returns ['77777']
```

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of Unicode alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore Unicode character. Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string. This means that `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo'`, `'foo.'`, `'(foo)'`, `'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar'` or `'foo3'`.